# c: cygwin- multiple definition of

Tags: c, cygwin, definitions

I'm a little stuck. I have almost finished this code but after trying to make it compatible for windows and linux, I came across this problem I can't solve. I haven't had too much experience in this area. Here are errors-

```
$ gcc client.c client.h clientdata.c clientdata.c -o client.exe
/tmp/ccHpxeKs.o:clientdata.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_handleSendingData'
/tmp/cclpyPee.o:clientdata.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccHpxeKs.o:clientdata.c:(.text+0xa9): multiple definition of `_handleRecievingData'
/tmp/cclpyPee.o:clientdata.c:(.text+0xa9): first defined here
/tmp/ccHpxeKs.o:clientdata.c:(.text+0xabb): multiple definition of `_replaceNewLineChar'
/tmp/cclpyPee.o:clientdata.c:(.text+0xabb): first defined here
/tmp/ccHpxeKs.o:clientdata.c:(.text+0xb1c): multiple definition of `_getMyTime'
```

...........

I have 4 files-
client.c-

```
#include "client.h"
#ifdef _WIN32
#include "clientdata.c"
#endif //win32
```

client.h-

```
#ifndef CLIENT
#define CLIENT

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAXSIZE 2048
#define MILLION  1000000.0

#ifdef _WIN32

#include <winsock.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "wsock32.lib")


#else

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#endif //win32

typedef enum {false = 0, true = 1, maybe = 2} bool;

struct messageNode
{
    struct timeval  *time1;
    struct timeval  *time2;
    int idNumber;
    char string[MAXSIZE];
    char stringClientArgs[MAXSIZE];
    struct messageNode* next;
    struct messageNode* moreNext;
    char redirectArgs[MAXSIZE];

} *head, *current;


int handleSendingData(struct messageNode *Node);
int handleRecievingData(struct messageNode *Node);
void printNode(struct messageNode *Node);
int setArgs(struct messageNode *Node, int command);
int setNode(struct messageNode* Node, int id);
int getArgs(struct messageNode* Node, char **newArgs);


#endif //CLIENT
```

clientdata.c-

```
#include "client.h"
#include "clientdata.h"
```

clientdata.h-

```
#ifndef CLIENTDATA
#define CLIENTDATA

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <process.h>
#endif //win32


void replaceNewLineChar(int count, ...);
void copyArray(char* str1, char* str2);
int addId(char *string, int id);
int getId(char *string);
int getReceivedArgs(char *string, char **newArgs, int number);
int getCommand(char* string);
int addToString(char *string, char *text);
int execute(char *cmd, char **args);
int getRedirectArgs(char *string, char **newArgs);
void getMyTime(struct timeval  *time);
double timeDifference(struct timeval  *start, struct timeval  *end);

#endif //CLIENTDATA
```

I am very new to this area and have looked over other questions but I'm not declaring and values in the headers, they are all function prototypes.
So lost! 
It was all working before I added the #ifdef win32 stuff :( but When I tried to change it back it still came up with these errors.

Comment: Is this the full source code? Client data contains only the headers?

Comment: Is your `clientdata.c` just the two lines ? Doesn't it has any definitions ? If yes, you are not supposed to include it in `client.c` as `#include "clientdata.c`.

Comment: sorry, I just added the 'includes'. There are all the functions in the corresponding .c files, from the headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look carefully at your compilation command line:

```
gcc client.c client.h clientdata.c clientdata.c -o client.exe
```

1. You don't need to pass header files to the compiler.
2. You don't want to pass the same source code twice (that's causing the multiple definition errors, because all the `extern` functions in `clientdata.c` are defined twice).

What you need is just:

```
gcc client.c clientdata.c -o client.exe
```

Comment: Hmm, that seems to have fixed it. I didn't even consider the console.... I was looking all though my code for over an hour :/ thanks!

Comment: That's a familiar problem.  It's awfully hard to find the solution when you're looking in the wrong place.  That's the advantage a new set of eyes.  (We've all looked in the wrong place for the solution to a problem.)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're including the same header multiple times. I suggest you use something like this in all your header files:

```
#ifndef UNIQUE_ID_FOR_THIS_HEADER
// All your header code here
#endif
```

PS: you never should include a .c file. If that file has no code, make it a .h file.

Comment: I only did that because I coudldn't get it to compile with windows, as I couldn't figure out how to manually compile the .c file in the command propmt. I very new to this windows part. Also, I do have the #ifndef for all headers.